# Плавное горизонтальное окрашивание текста

Tags: javascript, css

Мне нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы, при скролле к тексту, он единожды окрашивался в черный цвет. Грубо говоря заливался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>https://www.werkstatt.fr/project/citroen-origins</sub>

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать? Или расскажите как там это сделано.

Анимация закрашивания должна идти слева направо.

Answer (score 2):

В общих чертах оно работает следующим образом.

- Создается контейнер, в котором есть исходный текст.
- Затем, на каждую строчку создается отдельный элемент, который содержит в себе одну строчку. Этот элемент имеет абсолютное позиционирование и расположен точно над исходным текстом. Также он скрыт и обрезан (clip).
- При каком-то событии (в данном случае при скролле), наш отдельный элемент становится видимым и запускается анимация для изменения области обрезки(clip).

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/gLpjq7nf/).

Соответственно этот код конечно нужно еще улучшить - узнать ширину элемента, отступ сверху для следующей строчки, а также время запуска следующей анимации.
Также, на приведенной Вами в качестве примера странице, используют анимацию на jQuery.

```js
function addClass() {
  var $overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
  $overlay.style.clip =  'rect(0 '+$overlay.clientWidth+'px 24px 0)';
}

function removeClass() {
  var $overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
  $overlay.style.clip =  'rect(0 0 24px 0)';
}
```

```css
.conteiner {
  position: relative;
}

.origin {
  display: block;
  text-align: start;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  text-align: start;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip: rect(0px 0px 24px 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
  transition: clip 10s linear;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="origin">
    Notre feuille de route était claire : valoriser l’incroyable apport</div>
  <div class="overlay">Notre feuille de route était claire : valoriser l’incroyable apport </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="addClass()">
    Paint
  </button>

  <button onclick="removeClass()">
    unPaint
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать так, чтобы строки плавно заливались не зависимо от ширины?

Comment: Поскольку `clip: rect(0px 407px 24px 0px);` надо указывать конкретные цифры, то надо эти цифры узнать, например через `.clientWidth` у элемента.

Comment: @Александр, если данный ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный

Comment: Мне не совсем подходит этот вариант, мне нужно чтобы текст заливался не зависимо от ширины. Сайт адаптивный.

Comment: @Александр Я исправил ответ, теперь не зависит от ширины.

Comment: Спасибо, но когда текст переходит на следующую строку, на ней уже нет анимации заливки

Comment: @Александр Мы не должны делать задачу за Вас, мы помогаем с конкретной проблемой. Возможно, показываем направление, куда дальше смотреть. Никто за Вас целиком и полностью готовое решение, оттестированное во всех браузерах и оформленное в красивый плагин для `jQuery` делать **не будет**.

Comment: Так Вы меня направляете не в то русло. Мне по идее нужно брать каждую строку в отдельный класс, и уже работать с интервалом. Мне об этом здесь никто ничего не сказал, я сам до этого постепенно дохожу. Вот не знаю, как теперь задать этот интервал.

Comment: Какой интервал? Вы о чем? Про каждую строку у меня написано - *Затем, на каждую строчку создается отдельный элемент, который содержит в себе одну строчку. Этот элемент имеет абсолютное позиционирование и расположен точно над исходным текстом. Также он скрыт и обрезан (clip)*. Также про Ваш интервал написал *отступ сверху для следующей строчки, а также время запуска следующей анимации*. Вы ответ мой не читали?

Answer (score 2):

Вам понадобятся:

1. Определитель попадания элемента во вьюпорт (в этой демке не представлен), который будет навешивать класс на нужные вам элементы.
2. Псевдоэлемент `::before` - именно он будет являться заливкой
3. Анимация трансформации масштабирования этого псевдоэлемента. Трансформация используется потому что это одно из двух свойств, которое можно безболезненно анимировать.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector('.fill').classList.toggle('fill--filled');
}
```

```css
.fill {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fill--filled:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  animation: fill .5s;
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  },
  
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class=fill>Какой-то текст</p>

<button>Toggle fill</button>
```